# HD errors - boot failed again with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, hard-drive

Boom!
This morning it has happened again... even with my new hard disk bought just two days ago. :( :(

Like with my previous hard disk, I had to manually run `fsck` to repair all hard disk errors. After that Ubuntu boots normally.

What's going on?

Before I had a 2 Terabytes HD "Green label" by Western Digital, so I bought a more reliable 1 Terabytes "Black label".

I have installed the smartmontools also, to check the new hard disk. But the tool didn't find any error or problem.

I have no idea where or what I should investigate further...

**Motherboard info:**

```
sudo dmidecode -t 2
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASRock
    Product Name: N68-GS4 FX
    Version:                       
    Serial Number: M80-4C025302133
    Asset Tag: D05099606E79
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
    Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis:                       
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

**BIOS info:**

```
BIOS Information
Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
Version: P1.30
Release Date: 04/08/2015
Address: 0xF0000
Runtime Size: 64 kB
ROM Size: 1024 kB
```

**Processor info:**

```
Version: AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor
Voltage: 1.2 V
External Clock: 200 MHz
Max Speed: 3500 MHz
Current Speed: 3500 MHz
Status: Populated, Disabled By BIOS
Upgrade: Socket AM3
L1 Cache Handle: 0x0005
L2 Cache Handle: 0x0006
L3 Cache Handle: 0x0007
Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Core Count: 6
Core Enabled: 6
Thread Count: 6
Characteristics:
    64-bit capable
```

Comment: Did you shut down properly? No power cuts?

Comment: @Michal - Yes, shutdown from the Ubuntu main menu. Then the PC runs for few seconds and turnoff normally. No brutal power interruption.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an issue with faulty hardware.

Since you already did SMART self tests and found nothing wrong:

Try to update to latest BIOS version.

Check for bad RAM with memtest86+

Check for CPU errors with prime95.

You should also visually check your motherboard for visible issues like blown capacitors. It could even be your PSU.

Good luck!

Comment: What is a "PSU"???

Comment: PSU is Power Supply Unit.

Comment: So: I checked the RAM (memtest), the CPU (prime95) and the HD (smartmontools). Zero errors or warning or defects.
Neveverthe less I still have errors at the boot or after it. Today it took long time to boot and, after a minute or so, I've got the message:
"systemd-jpurnal[256]: failed to send WATCHDOG=1 .... connection refused".

Comment: Furthermore, after logging in the sustem I always get exactly 9 (nine) error messages from the system about files located in folders usually used by the OS (i.e. /var, /bin... etc.).
I usually close all this error windows with the mouse and the system continue to work "normally".

Comment: Last but not the last, the 1.30 BIOS version that is is installed is the most recent available, as reported from the official website of ASRock: http://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68-GS4%20FX/index.de.asp?cat=Download&os=BIOS

Comment: Have you reinstalled Ubuntu to get a fresh start?

Comment: Check your installation media integrity: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

Comment: And check your download integrity: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify

Comment: And if your important system files keep getting corrupted we have really ruled out any possibility of software issues. These are classic symptoms of hardware failure, even a faulty power supply could be the issue.

Comment: I have reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 two times. It works for few days and then...
When running `fdisk -l`I get the message `Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.` The misalignment of logical/physical sectors could be the reason of such file corruptions???

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I've the same issue. I moved from 'failed' WD blue drive to a WD black. Worked for a couple of months (occasionally crashed after logging in), now the new black drive has failed.